# Remove white space when using *ngIf = "pet.doado === false"

Tags: html, angular7

When I use `*ngIf = "pet.doado === false"` to filter the data displayed on the front end, there is a blank space:

[image]

Code:

```
<div class="row content">
    <div class="col-sm-2 teste" *ngFor="let pet of pets | async">
        <mat-card class="example-card" *ngIf="pet.doado === false">
            <mat-card-header>
                <mat-card-title>{{pet.nome}}</mat-card-title>
                <mat-card-subtitle>Idade: {{pet.idade}}</mat-card-subtitle>
            </mat-card-header>
            <img mat-card-image src="{{pet.foto}}" alt="Foto Pet" class="imagePet">
            <mat-card-content>
                <p>
                    Tamanho: {{pet.tamanho}}
                    <br />Cor: {{pet.cor}}
                    <br />Sexo: {{pet.sexo}}
                    <br />
                    <br />Pessoa Responsavel: {{pet.nomeUser}}
                    <br />Telefone: {{pet.telefoneUser}}
                    <br />Está no Bairro: {{pet.bairro}}
                </p>
            </mat-card-content>
        </mat-card>
    </div>
</div>
```

Code Correct:

```
<div class="row content">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let pet of pets | async">
        <div class="col-sm-2 teste" *ngIf="pet.doado === false">
            <mat-card class="example-card">
                <mat-card-header>
                    <mat-card-title>{{pet.nome}}</mat-card-title>
                    <mat-card-subtitle>Idade: {{pet.idade}}</mat-card-subtitle>
                </mat-card-header>
                <img mat-card-image src="{{pet.foto}}" alt="Foto Pet" class="imagePet">
                <mat-card-content>
                    <p>
                        Tamanho: {{pet.tamanho}}
                        <br />Cor: {{pet.cor}}
                        <br />Sexo: {{pet.sexo}}
                        <br />
                        <br />Pessoa Responsavel: {{pet.nomeUser}}
                        <br />Telefone: {{pet.telefoneUser}}
                        <br />Está no Bairro: {{pet.bairro}}
                    </p>
                </mat-card-content>
            </mat-card>
        </div>
    </ng-container>
</div>
```

I added a container using `ngFor` and added `ngIf` to div.

Comment: The  rendered HTML could be quite helpful in this situation.

Comment: Can you share the CSS as well?

Answer (score 2):

That's because there's a `col-sm-2` wrapper div above the div with `ngIf` statement that takes this space.

Assuming that your class `teste` doesn't take up any width, you could put the `col-sm-2` along with the `ngIf` in a wrapper `div`

Eg:

```
<div class="row content">
    <div class="teste" *ngFor="let pet of pets | async">
       <!-- Wrapper div which takes col-sm-2 only on ngIf -->
       <div class="col-sm-2" *ngIf="pet.doado === false">
        <mat-card class="example-card">
            <mat-card-header>
                <mat-card-title>{{pet.nome}}</mat-card-title>
                <mat-card-subtitle>Idade: {{pet.idade}}</mat-card-subtitle>
            </mat-card-header>
            <img mat-card-image src="{{pet.foto}}" alt="Foto Pet" class="imagePet">
            <mat-card-content>
                <p>
                    Tamanho: {{pet.tamanho}}
                    <br />Cor: {{pet.cor}}
                    <br />Sexo: {{pet.sexo}}
                    <br />
                    <br />Pessoa Responsavel: {{pet.nomeUser}}
                    <br />Telefone: {{pet.telefoneUser}}
                    <br />Está no Bairro: {{pet.bairro}}
                </p>
            </mat-card-content>
        </mat-card>
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I used your answer as a base but I did the code differently, I put my updated code in the question.

Comment: Sure. Many ways to do it. Just wanted to point what you were missing